# isolating for a variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to isolate for a variable (I) in a  [paper](http://docdro.id/yNSgQzV) characterizing the operation of a solar panel, but I'm not sure what the most effective approach would be. Would this be a job for Mathematica, or is it trivial to do by hand?

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_solar_cells#Characteristic_equation) has a solution using the Lambert W function to a similar equation, so perhaps it can be done similarly to the one from the paper.

What's the best approach for actually evaluating the lambert W function?

[image]
[image]

Comment: That is surely not trivial..

Comment: The Lambert W function would seem to be the only "neat" and "closed" form solution possible, but from my experience with the LW function, I doubt this is solvable.  I would probably aim for numerical methods.

Comment: @SimpleArt I updated my question with a solution to a similar equation from Wikipedia using your suggested Lambert W function. Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the original equation based on the solution to the second one? If not, what type of numerical methods would you suggest to use? Thanks

Comment: @waspinator Your original problem has too many terms to be solvable in terms of the Lambert W function (the Lambert W function is designed to handle exponential + monomial problems), so numerical methods should be preferred.  Probably Newton's method?  I'm not sure, you could add an approximation tag for more experienced users in that subject.